# 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages' must be enabled in DjangoTemplates

Tags: django

When I try to migrate or createsuperuser in my project I get this error.

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (admin.E404) 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages' must be enabled in DjangoTemplates (TEMPLATES) in order to use the admin application.
```

I shouldn't be getting error since it's a starter project and I'm not even using templates.
This parameter 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages' is present in settings.py, TEMPLATES

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Can the issue be from a third-part app, since I added one called 'tinymce' to my INSTALLED_APPS 
https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce

Comment: What is not clear about the error?

Comment: Edited the question @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: you *are* using Django templates. For example the admin page uses Django templates.

Comment: 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages' is present in settings.py templates @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: What Django version are you using? Looks like this might be an old(er) one then?

Comment: It's the latest one. 2.2

Comment: I was using another app in INSTALLED_APPS. Could the issue be from that?

Comment: do you have, by any chance multiple elements in `TEMPLATES`? Can you share that part in the question?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It's from the third-party app. I removed it from INSTALLED_APPS and the issue is gone. Now the question is can I fix that one or not? can you help me with that. Here is the repo https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce

Comment: @SaadatEsmaeliy: it looks to me it is simply not compatible with the latest Django versions. Probaby it did not take into account some setting redesigns.

Comment: your answer was right. just mention it could be from a 3rd party and I will upvote it

Answer (score 4):

**Enabling messages**

Messages are implemented through a middleware class and corresponding context processor.

The default settings.py created by django-admin startproject already contains all the settings required to enable message functionality:

**`'django.contrib.messages'` is in INSTALLED_APPS.**

**MIDDLEWARE contains `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'` and `'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware'`.**

The default storage backend relies on sessions. That’s why `SessionMiddleware` must be enabled and appear before `MessageMiddleware` in MIDDLEWARE.

**The `'context_processors'` option of the DjangoTemplates backend defined in your TEMPLATES setting contains `'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'`.**

**If you don’t want to use messages, you can remove `'django.contrib.messages'` from your INSTALLED_APPS, the `MessageMiddleware` line from MIDDLEWARE, and the messages context processor from TEMPLATES.**

**More about**: https://django.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.x/ref/contrib/messages.html

Answer (score 3):

You assume right. It's because of tinymce.
This was happened because you export environmental variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to a file that doesn't exist. You run this code.

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='testtinymce.settings'
```

Don't worry. You can fix it by the same action that got you in trouble. You need to set this environmental variable to your django project setting. Like code below:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='<project_folder>.settings'
```

Good luck.